# Get user country from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user's current country from Facebook . I'm able to fetch data like email , id, last name , first name etc , but when it comes to country i can't find the right code . Can someone tell me the required permissions as well as how to fetch the data from the object.

Currently these are my permissions

`loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));`

And i'm fetching data like this

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("JSON", "" + response.getJSONObject().toString());
                    try {
                        name = object.getString("name");
                        first_name = object.optString("first_name");
                        last_name = object.optString("last_name");
                        fname.setText(first_name);
                        lname.setText(last_name);
                        e_mail.setText(email);
                        dp1.setProfileId(object.optString("id"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            /*AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);*/
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(large)");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current location, this is how to do it:

Just request the right permissions such as `user_location` and after that,

**Edit**

Use this line of code :

```
 String currentCity = obj.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
```

as:

```
                  try {
                        name = object.getString("name");
                        first_name = object.optString("first_name");
                        last_name = object.optString("last_name");
                        String currentCity = obj.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                        fname.setText(first_name);
                        lname.setText(last_name);
                        e_mail.setText(email);
                        dp1.setProfileId(object.optString("id"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Also add `location` in following:

```
  parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,location,picture.type(large)");
```

Comment: 'obj.getJSONObject("location")'.getString("name"); ' 
Not working . 
How can i use graphObject ?

Comment: @Shahal I just suggested that, you can use as you are using other code. check for edit.

Comment: sorry bro . it was my fault , i forgot to add location to bundles .

Comment: @Shahal Hope it helped.

Comment: Yeah , it did . I got one more problem . I used the same code for another project there when i click the login button i'm getting a Facebook page where it says **You are not logged in. Please login and try again** . Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: @Shahal I don't know why this happening. but may be some coding error. You can ask a new question with some code snippet, so that i can get a clue why this is happening. Thanks.